# Files in woocommerce folder(integrate with theme) is not working after update woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have updated woocommerce from version 2.6.8 to latest version 3.3.3. I have so many customization in woocommerce folder that are integrated with theme. But after I update the woocommerce the files is not working.

I have already latest version of wordpress 4.9.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to change original theme woocommerce folder in your current theme folder than recheck your customized code and than check those files in woocommerce template folder, and also check your code and compare with woocommerce template.

I don't know how much you customize in how many files you customize, so i can not say properly that what code you should change.

Thanks